# Migrate database from Mysql to Postgres in YII2 .How to ignore the string case of Table Name and Column Name

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I migrated database from Mysql to Postgres. Some Table Name and Column Name changed to be lower case.
In my yii2 code, I must to find all the names and modify them.
Is there any setting or method that allows me to globally ignore case?

Comment: globally ignore case WHERE? PHP or POSTGRESS or MySQL or somewhere else

Comment: @RiggsFolly ignore case in yii2. like 
return $this->hasOne(Log::className(), ['id' => 'lockLogId']);
Here lockLogId is used by mysql, but in pgsql, it's locklogid

Comment: @clara you might have to make those changes manually in Yii2 since in Yii2 table and column names are case sensitive. The alternate is to rename columns in Postgres using `alter table test rename column locklogid to "lockLogId"`